# Mongodb - search by Date only using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

m using poco like this

```
public class Log
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        [BsonDateTimeOptions(Kind = DateTimeKind.Local)]
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        public LogLevel Level { get; set; }       
        [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
        public TraceLogEntity Exception { get; set; }
    }
```

and then to get values from Mongo m using

```
var filter = Builders<Log>.Filter.Empty;
 filter &= Builders<Log>.Filter.Where(l => l.DateTime.Equals(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()));    
var collection = _context.Log.Find(filter).Limit(100).ToList();
```

i dont know why i get object reference not to set to instance of an object 
if i comment datetime check then every thing works

can some one help me how to fix the issue

Stack Trace

```
at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.Serialize(IBsonSerializer serializer, BsonSerializationContext context, Object value)
   at MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.IBsonSerializerExtensions.ToBsonValue(IBsonSerializer serializer, Object value)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateComparison(Expression variableExpression, ExpressionType operatorType, ConstantExpression constantExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateEquals(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.TranslateMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate(Expression node, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Translators.PredicateTranslator.Translate[TDocument](Expression`1 predicate, IBsonSerializer`1 parameterSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFilterDefinition`1.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.CreateFindOperation[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.ToList[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

value saved in DB

[image]

Comment: What is your c# driver version ?

Comment: C# driver - 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be bug around implicit casting and null reference in 2.4.2. Both the bugs are fixed in 2.4.3

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1922 & https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1894

Btw I should note you are trying to compare string date with date type which is valid in expression and C# driver takes care of casting it to date.

You've couple of options.

Upgrade to 2.4.3

Other option is to use date types. Both variants below should work fine in 2.4.2.

```
filter &= Builders<Log>.Filter.Where(l => l.DateTime.Equals(DateTime.Now));

filter &= Builders<Log>.Filter.Eq(l => l.DateTime, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: i have upgraded to 2.4.3 now it doesnt throw error but i m not getting any thing back , i just want to compare date not time

Comment: i have added value that is saved in DB